# what's the page life cycle in Ajax call in Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

what's the page life cycle in Ajax call in Asp.net?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> An AJAX-enabled ASP.NET page raises
>   the same server life-cycle events as
>   an ASP.NET 2.0 Web page and in
>   addition raises client life-cycle
>   events.

[AJAX Client Life-Cycle Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386417.aspx) from MSDN. or [ASP.NET AJAX Client Life-Cycle Events](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/overview/AJAXClientEvents.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

An asynchronous postback behaves much like a synchronous postback. All the server page life-cycle events occur, and view state and form data are preserved. However, in the rendering phase, only the contents of the UpdatePanel control are sent to the browser. The rest of the page remains unchanged.